# File reading - how to?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a program. I ran into this issue where the program could not find the file when calling the `changeRating` method but it did not have a problem when calling the `getRating` method. They are both in the same class and i do not know why this would happen.

Here is code :)

```
   public void changeRating(int amount, AssetManager am)
   {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("rating.txt"));
        pw.print(Integer.parseInt(getRating(am))+amount+"");
        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Rating file not found while adding rating");
    }



    }
    public String getRating(AssetManager am)
    {
    String r = "";
    try {
        InputStream input = am.open("rating.txt");
        r = getTextFromInputStream(input);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Rating file not found while fetching rating ");
    }
    return r;
}
```

I Keep getting the error that says "Rating file not found while adding rating". The method `changeRating` is supposed to overwrite the file entirely with the new rating. And the `getRating` is supposed to get the rating from an input stream i made which already works.

Comment: `new File("rating.txt")`.You cannot only supply a file name. You should supply a full path.

Comment: GetRating() reads a file from assets. Its ok to use only a file name there. Very strange that you did not mention in your post that you read a file from assets.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the mention that i was using an asset manager before. I still do not know how to reference that file called rating.txt. it is inside the assets folder in the main folder.

Comment: What are you talking about? GetRating() does work isnt it?

Comment: getRating does work. it uses an asset manager to get that file as an input stream. in the method changeRating im trying to change the whole file which just consists of a number. it gives an ioexception each time i use change rating, resulting in "Rating file not found while adding rating"

Comment: Yes you already told that. Why repeat yourself? You better read the things i told you that you did wrong. Or had a wrong idea about.

Comment: i know you told me to supply a file path but i was wondering why i dont have to supply a path for the method getRating.

Comment: `im trying to change the whole file`. No. You are not trying to do so. Luckyly you are not trying as files in assets are read only. Strange that you cannot tell what you are actually doing.

Comment: `know you told me to supply a file path but i was wondering why i dont have to supply a path for the method getRating.`. That is a nonsense comparison. Not to the point. In the first one you read a file from assets. In the second one you are trying to write a file to the file system. The latter has nothing to do with assets.

Comment: ok then i think ive narrowed my issue down to how to reference the file.
It is located in app/src/main/assets/rating.txt. I want to use a relative path and but it keeps saying file not found

Comment: ???? What do you mean ?? Referencing a file?

Comment: You ate messing around with a full path that you think leads to the assets folder. But does not. Makes no sense. YOU CANNOT CHANGE A FILE IN ASSETS.

Comment: referencing as in when im trying to use this line:
`PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("rating.txt"));`
it says file not found, am telling java where to find the file correctly?

Comment: My god... why do you ask that? My first comment was `new File("rating.txt").You cannot only supply a file name. You should supply a full path. `.